# Can't run bookmarklets on browser (chrome) without Wifi connection

Tags: chrome-for-android, internet, scripts, bookmarks, javascript

I have some bookmarks that are javascript code (for example, `javascript:alert(1)`) but am not able to run them unless I am on a webpage that is not the "newtab" page.

Which is particularly problematic when I don't have an internet connection. As I couldn't load a(ny) webpage, I couldn't run the bookmarklets.

Is there a solution to this problem?